# How to return the subview that was touched

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've searched around on here and see a lot of answers that say to turn on the userInteractionEnabled property. I've already done that.

I create my subviews programmatically (not in Interface Builder). The subviews are a custom subclass of UIView (called PieceSuperClass).

All I want is something that would look like

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];

UIView *hitView = [self.view hitTest:currentPosition withEvent:event];

if ([hitView isKindOfClass:[PieceSuperClass class]]) {
    return hitView;
}
```

For some reason, `hitView` `isKindOfClass` `UIImageView` even though I most definitely declared it as a `PieceSuperClass`. 'PieceSuperClass' is a subclass of UIImageView.

```
// Draw proper piece 
UIImage *pieceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.png", pieceColor, pieceName]]; 
PieceSuperClass *pieceImageView = [[PieceSuperClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 39, 38)]; 
pieceImageView.image = pieceImage; 
pieceImageView.identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", pieceColor, pieceName, pieceNumber]; 
pieceImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; 
[boardView addSubview:pieceImageView];
```

Comment: Does your `PieceSuperClass` have a `UIImageView` subview? The call to `hitTest:withEvent:` returns the deepest subview at the given point.

Comment: It does indeed: // Draw proper piece
    UIImage *pieceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.png", pieceColor, pieceName]];
    PieceSuperClass *pieceImageView = [[PieceSuperClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 39, 38)];
    pieceImageView.image = pieceImage;
    pieceImageView.identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", pieceColor, pieceName, pieceNumber];
    pieceImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [boardView addSubview:pieceImageView];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
- (id)whichPieceTouched:touches withEvent:event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];

for (int i = 0; i < [piecesArray count]; i++) {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([[piecesArray objectAtIndex:i] frame], currentPosition)) {
        return [piecesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }
}
```

Though I have one lingering problem: it seems to always select the object about 20 pixels below (or the next object down).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are tracking the wrong view with the currectposition. If the PieceSuperClass is a subview of your self.view you should probably track it like:

```
CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view.subviews];
```

Comment: As written, this results in a warning: "Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSArray *' to parameter of type 'UIView *'"

Answer (score 0):

That's from the [UITouch Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The view in which the touch initially occurred. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIView *view

So you can know which view was touched and simply do this:

```
UIView *hitView = touch.view;
if ([hitView isKindOfClass:[PieceSuperClass class]]) {
    return hitView;
}
```

Comment: That makes intuitive sense but I get this: po hitView
(UIView *) $1 = 0x0bd61d10 <UIImageView: 0xbd61d10; frame = (0 -64; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbd621e0>> meaning that the if statement is not satisfied